# Clear a list of variables and also another variable besides the list

Tags: matlab, variables

I am saving all parameters from workspace with `Param = who;` and then I have a loop whose index `i` I want to keep too, besides the parameters in the list. But apparently I cannot do:

```
clear -except Param{:} i
```

How can I keep both the list and the index?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`clearvars`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/clearvars.html) with `'-except'` option. You need to use [function syntax](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html), as your variable names are stored in a cell array:

```
clearvars('-except', Param{:}, 'i')
```

If you need to keep the variable `Param` as well:

```
clearvars('-except', Param{:}, 'i', 'Param')
```

Comment: Theproblem is that all parameters in the list and the index change every loop, and I would need to do clearvars('-except', Param{:}, 'i') every loop. But the list gets deleted, making the next call of clearvars impossible

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to keep the `Param` variable as well. See edited answer

Comment: Should've thought at that..Thanks.